How to filter pull request events to a GitHub App
When you create a GitHub App you can choose to subscribe to different events. For example the "Pull request" event.
This means that the webhook endpoint you have implemented receives a request with a json body every time an action happens to a pull request. That can be both on assignments, close, opened, review requested and so on. If you have a popular app that means that your webhook will get a lot of requests.
Is there a way to filter these events before they reach my webhook endpoint? I'm only interested in events where the action is "opened". Everything else is just spamming and putting an unnecessary load on my server.
